# Custom Re deployments from My Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ant, myeclipse

Experts
When we redeploy any application from an IDE such as MYEclipse , it just redeploys the .class files. I want to customize the eclipse developer, so the deployer can also deploy the custom files (other than class files).

Should i write any custom ANT script for Myeclipse or any custom settings the My Eclipse provides us ?

Answer (score 0):

IDEs along the classes and libraries usually deploy everything they find in the `web` / `www-root` folder (in the folder that contains the `WEB-INF` and `META-INF`).

So you can configure your deployed applications structure using the IDE by structuring the content of that folder.

If it still doesn't fit your needs, then `ANT` would be the best option.

In my opinion `ANT` is always the best option, but using the development environment's functionality is proven faster then writing an ant build file.

Say, if you're developing a **`web service`**, a **`web application`** consuming that service, and a **`library`** that both the service and the webapp uses, then with a single (and not even long or difficult) ant file you can build them, create the aar, war and jar files and deploy them all in their correct places, eg. under axis, inside the global lib folder, and in the webapps folder. 
All these in one step.